# Sitecore Indexing GetLocalDatasourceDependencies

Tags: azure, indexing

Sitecore 8.2 update 5 on Azure App Services. Anyone knows what could be the reason

```
<pipelines>         
    <indexing.getDependencies>
        <processor type="Custom.Infrastructure.Pipelines.GetLocalDatasourceDependencies, Custom.Assembly" />
        <!-- When indexing an item that is used as a datasource, make sure that all the items that reference the datasource in their presentation details gets re-indexed as well. -->
        <processor type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Pipelines.GetDependencies.GetDatasourceDependencies, Sitecore.ContentSearch"/>
    </indexing.getDependencies>
</pipelines>
```

Error message:

```
Exception: System.NullReferenceException
Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source: Sitecore.ContentSearch
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Pipelines.GetDependencies.GetDatasourceDependencies.<>c.<GetSourceUris>b__1_0(ItemLink l)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<DistinctIterator>d__64`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.InsertRange(Int32 index, IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Pipelines.GetDependencies.GetDatasourceDependencies.Process(GetDependenciesArgs context)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Abstractions.CorePipelineWrapper.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Pipelines.GetDependencies.GetDependenciesPipeline.GetIndexingDependencies(IIndexable indexable)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Crawler`1.UpdateDependents(IProviderUpdateContext context, T indexable)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler.DoUpdate(IProviderUpdateContext context, SitecoreIndexableItem indexable, IndexEntryOperationContext operationContext)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler.Update(IProviderUpdateContext context, IIndexableUniqueId indexableUniqueId, IndexEntryOperationContext operationContext, IndexingOptions indexingOptions)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.AbstractSearchIndex.<>c__DisplayClass94_2.<PerformUpdate>b__0(IndexableInfo info, ParallelLoopState parallelLoopState)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass17_0`1.<ForWorker>b__1()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvokeWithArg(Task childTask)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c__DisplayClass176_0.<ExecuteSelfReplicating>b__0(Object <p0>)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetDatasourceDependencies` checks for all the dependencies.

In the background it uses `LinkDatabase` to get all the referrers and referred items.

If there is an item link in the `LinkDatabase` but the items from the link are no longer in database, it may result in null reference exception.

Solution: rebuild the link database.

Comment: thanks marek, I had triggered rebuilding link db , but the process errored out

Comment: What is the error? I think that's another issue that you have to fix first. Maybe post another question about the exception while rebuilding link database if you cannot fix it on your own?

Comment: Yes , trying to check out what is the error while rebuilding links , but on azure app services , difficult to get the actual error

Comment: Maybe try running "Clean up databases" first?

Comment: Thanks , truncated core db links table there were 5L records, but app services are excruciatingly slow

Comment: I meant "Clean up databases" task from Sitecore control panel ;)

Comment: Cleanup Task Runner - RebuildDescendants on master finished
Job ended: CleanupTaskRunner (units processed: )
 no value in units processed , is that ok ?

Comment: Tbh I don't know. Did it help? Can you rebuild link database from control panel now? or still errors?